# How to read an Excel file as a data frame

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, bar-chart

I'm trying to make some barplots with data from the IMF. I tried to read the xls file with read.table():

```
base <- read.table("http://www.imf.org/external/pubs/ft/weo/2017/02/weodata/WEOOct2017all.xls", header=TRUE, sep="\t", fill=TRUE)
```

However, the data is saved as a list:

```
typeof(base)
[1] "list"
```

And I don't know how to extract the data to make a barplot. For example, I want to graph the variable "NGDP_RPCH", for the country "ARG" and the years 2010-2019 (columns 40-49 in the excel).

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
graph <- base[which((base[2]=="ARG")&(base[3]=='NGDP_RPCH')),40:49]
graph
[1] X2010 X2011 X2012 X2013 X2014 X2015 X2016 X2017 X2018 X2019
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I would like to know how to save the data as a data frame, or how to extract a vector of data from the list, so I could run:

```
barplot(graph).
```

Comment: The title of the duplicate references .xlsx files, but the solutions presented there generally work for both those and older .xls files as well.

Comment: For any data.frame, it's true `typeof(base)=="list"`. Use `class()`, not `typeof()` to see how an object behaves, not how it's stored. I would guess `class(base)` is "data.frame"

Comment: For your second question, there is no "NGDP_RPCH" for "ARG" as the country. Are you sure "NGDP_RPCH" is the correct variable?

Comment: File 228 of the excel: 213 ARG NGDP_RPCH Argentina

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, use an appropriate tool to import Excel files. This may include the packages **readxl**, **openxlsx**, **XLConnect**, **xlsx**, etc.

```
library(readxl)
base <- read_excel("~/Desktop/WEOOct2017all.xls")
```

Then use `[[` to select a single column, not `[`.

```
graph <- base[which((base[[2]]=="ARG")&(base[[3]]=='NGDP_RPCH')),40:49]
```

And convert to a matrix to use `barplot`.

```
barplot(as.matrix(graph))
```